# Embed JavaScript in HTML report

Tags: jasper-reports

How do you embed JavaScript into HTML reports?

Is it possible? If so where can I find examples?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Consider generating an HTML report fragment and embed that HTML fragment into a web page. Then, in the header of the complete web page, include JavaScript that manipulates the report HTML as desired.

The following will not work:

1. Add Static Text to the Title Band (or any other).
2. Change the Markup property to `html`.
3. Change the text to `<script>alert( 'hello' );</script>`.
4. Export as HTML.

This is because the HTML markup is a subset of HTML.

Your other option is to write a [Scriptlet](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/scriptlet/index.html).